# Python NLTK: How to retrieve percentage confidence in classifier prediction

Tags: python, nlp, machine-learning, classification, nltk

I am currently training an NLTK classifier to recognize motion commands.  These commands can include "move left", "please move forward", "halt!", "move towards the right", etc.

I am currently using the classifier based on a few key features (such as the existence of "halt" and "left") to classify information, and it works fine.

However, let us presume the following text, "move to the left right", is given.  In this case, both keywords are conflicting each other, and presumably, the classifier should have a low confidence level when offering its resultant prediction.

As such, is there any way to retrieve the confidence of its predicted "direction", after using `<CLASSIFIER>.classify()` ?

NOTE: I have tried to use `nltk.classify.accuracy()` but it is only for use on a test data-set, not a single query.

Answer (score 2):

Some classifiers in NLTK have a [`prob_classify`](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#nltk.classify.api.ClassifierI.prob_classify) method, which returns a probability distribution over all possible outcomes. From this you can compute a confidence scores such as [odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds) or [log-odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit). For a percentage score, you can just take the probability of the most likely outcome.

Comment: This doesn't tell you how confident NLTK is of the answer, though. Just how likely it thinks the competing analyses are.

Comment: Hmm I am taking a look at an SVM-based classifier in NLTK now.. apparently it has this resolve_prediction which should return the confidence in the guess.  Hope it works.

Comment: @toiletfreak: `resolve_prediction` has nothing to do with confidence scores. What's wrong with `prob_classify`?